# While loop does not execute

Tags: bash, shell

I currently have this code:

```
listing=$(find "$PWD")
fullnames=""
while read listing;
do
    if [ -f "$listing" ]
        then
            path=`echo "$listing" | awk -F/ '{print $(NF)}'`
            fullnames="$fullnames $path"
            echo $fullnames
    fi 
done
```

For some reason, this script isn't working, and I think it has something to do with the way that I'm writing the while loop / declaring listing.  Basically, the code is supposed to pull out the actual names of the files, i.e. blah.txt, from the find $PWD.

Comment: try ding - - - **while [ read listing; ] do**                                    Example - here http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: @AtulOHolic That's not even close to right.

Comment: Ohh, my bad. I was only trying to help. Thanks for correcting. :)

Answer (score 6):

`read listing` does not read a value from the string `listing`; it sets the value of `listing` with a line read from standard input. Try this:

```
# Ignoring the possibility of file names that contain newlines
while read; do
    [[ -f $REPLY ]] || continue
    path=${REPLY##*/}
    fullnames+=( $path )
    echo "${fullnames[@]}"
done < <( find "$PWD" )
```

With `bash` 4 or later, you can simplify this with

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*; do
    [[ -f $f ]] || continue
    path+=( "$f" )
done
fullnames=${paths[@]##*/}
```

Comment: Is `$REPLY` the default variable name for the `while read`? Otherwise I don't understand it.

Comment: Apparently so @fedorqui (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) - I learned something new too :)

Comment: Note that `while read; do ...; done < <(find "$PWD")` is often written  `find . | while read ...`, with the side effect of the while loop running in a subshell.

Comment: Not only is using `REPLY` less typing by itself, but the entire line   (including trailing and leading whitespace) is included.